# JQuery set textbox collection to empty value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, input

How do i go about emptying the values of textboxes here is below code i h've worked out but doesn't seem to work

```
var txtName = $("input#txtName"),txtPrice = $("input#txtPrice");
```

#### First Method

```
$(txtName,txtPrice).val("");
```

- this is actually wrong because the price textbox would now become the context to search within i suppose.

#### Second Method

```
$([txtName,txtPrice]).val("");
```

- I don't understand why i should do this as they are already jQuery Objects(But works)

I Put them in variables as these are used further in the script.

Comment: Seems to me the reason why the first method didn't work and the second one did is because they approach different methods. The definition to jquery's init method is : 
init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery )     so the first method set the selector and context and the second one only the selector. ( the selector can also be node types, and array of not types. see jquery's code )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a few ways to do it;

```
txtName.add(txtPrice).val("");
// OR
$("input#txtName,input#txtPrice").val("");
```

(There is a `$` sign in your `txtPrice` input by the way.)

First Method didn't work because it's a way of using jQuery selector. When you use jQuery like that first parameter will be the selector and second will be the container object where the selector works. Basically it's almost same thing like this;

```
$(txtPrice).find(txtName).val("");
```

Because there is no `txtName` in `txtPrice` neither value will be emptied.

Second Method works because you're giving your parameters as an array to jQuery selector. It accepts it and does `.val()` action to every element of array. This way is legit but because your variables already jQuery objects there is no need to use this.

Comment: `$("input#txtName,input#txtPrice")` works but i avoided it because i will require those textboxes further down the script and at that point walking through dom is waste of resource.

Comment: Than [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method suits best I guess. It doesn't modify original collection. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/xQx4e/) example

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text]').val('');
```

or

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){ $(this).val(''); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your variables here:

```
var txtName = $("input#txtName"),txtPrice = $("input#txtPrice");
```

You can directly access jQuery methods like so:

```
txtName.val("");
txtPrice.val("");
```

Because they are *already* jQuery objects. There is no need to try to wrap them in the `$()` jQuery function again.

As far as I can see, the only way the [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) accepts an array is when the array elements are DOM elements, not jQuery objects. (If it works with jQuery objects that doesn't seem to be covered in the doco, and when I tried it it didn't work for me.) So given that you know each of your jQuery objects only has one element (because you selected on ID), you could try this:

```
$([txtName[0],txtPrice[0]]).val("");
```

But that is still going to create a new jQuery object that holds both elements, so it seems a bit redundant when you can just do it the way I first mentioned.

(Note also that in your selector "input#txtName" the "input" part is redundant since you then select by id and id is (or should be) unique on the page.)

EDIT: if you had a really long list of variables and wanted to save typing another way to do it would be like this:

```
$.each([txtName,txtPrice,txtTest1,txtTest2,txtTest3],function(i,v) { v.val(""); });
```

Comment: Wouldn't i save some space and typing by wrapping it again with jQuery? also jquery was primary written to solve these sort of iterative tasks

Comment: You may save a tiny bit of typing, but given you are already concerned about efficient code (you mention that you created the variables so you can use them in multiple places) why would you want to create another (temporary) jQuery object just to set the values?

Answer (score 0):

Surprising that this worked,
`$([txtName,txtPrice]).each(function(){this.val("")});`